# How to pinch and scroll an image in SwiftUI?

Tags: image, scroll, swiftui, pinch

I want to add an image viewer in my application but I have trouble implementing it. I want to display an image and allow the user to pinch and scroll in the image to examine it in details. Based on what I've gathered from multiple Internet posts, I have something kinda working, but not exactly. Here is my code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var currentScale: CGFloat = 1.0
    @State var previousScale: CGFloat = 1.0

    @State var currentOffset = CGSize.zero
    @State var previousOffset = CGSize.zero

    var body: some View {

        ZStack {

            Image("bulldog2")
                .resizable()
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .offset(x: self.currentOffset.width, y: self.currentOffset.height)
                .scaleEffect(self.currentScale)
                .gesture(DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { value in
                        let deltaX = value.translation.width - self.previousOffset.width
                        let deltaY = value.translation.height - self.previousOffset.height
                        self.previousOffset.width = value.translation.width
                        self.previousOffset.height = value.translation.height
                        self.currentOffset.width = self.currentOffset.width + deltaX / self.currentScale
                        self.currentOffset.height = self.currentOffset.height + deltaY / self.currentScale }
                    .onEnded { value in self.previousOffset = CGSize.zero })
                .gesture(MagnificationGesture()
                    .onChanged { value in
                        let delta = value / self.previousScale
                        self.previousScale = value
                        self.currentScale = self.currentScale * delta
                }
                .onEnded { value in self.previousScale = 1.0 })

            VStack {

                Spacer()

                HStack {
                    Text("Menu 1").padding().background(Color.white).cornerRadius(30).padding()
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Menu 2").padding().background(Color.white).cornerRadius(30).padding()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The initial view looks like this:

[image]

The first problem I have is that I can move the image too far in the way that I can see outside of the image. This can cause the image not to be not visible in the application anymore if it moved too far.

[image]

The second problem, which is not a big one, is that I can scale down the image but it becomes too small compared to the view. I want to constraint it so that "fit" would be its smallest size. Is there a better way than constraining `self.currentScale` and `self.previousScale`?

[image]

The third problem is that if I change the image to fill the space, the bottom menu gets larger that the phone's screen.

[image]

I'm not an iOS developer and there is probably a much better way to implement this feature. Thanks for you help.

Comment: You _are_ an iOS Developer, because you developed code for iOS. Welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can answer 2 of 3 questions. I can't repeat the third one.

1. you can use `GeometryReader` and use it's `frame` and `size` to make some constraints (I'll show it in example below);
2. maybe the most simplest and better way is just to use `max` function, like `.scaleEffect(max(self.currentScale, 1.0))`.

Here is changed example:

```swift
struct BulldogImageViewerView: View {
    @State var currentScale: CGFloat = 1.0
    @State var previousScale: CGFloat = 1.0

    @State var currentOffset = CGSize.zero
    @State var previousOffset = CGSize.zero

    var body: some View {

        ZStack {

            GeometryReader { geometry in // here you'll have size and frame

                Image("bulldog")
                    .resizable()
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .offset(x: self.currentOffset.width, y: self.currentOffset.height)
                    .scaleEffect(max(self.currentScale, 1.0)) // the second question
                    .gesture(DragGesture()
                        .onChanged { value in

                            let deltaX = value.translation.width - self.previousOffset.width
                            let deltaY = value.translation.height - self.previousOffset.height
                            self.previousOffset.width = value.translation.width
                            self.previousOffset.height = value.translation.height

                            let newOffsetWidth = self.currentOffset.width + deltaX / self.currentScale
                            // question 1: how to add horizontal constraint (but you need to think about scale)
                            if newOffsetWidth <= geometry.size.width - 150.0 && newOffsetWidth > -150.0 {
                                self.currentOffset.width = self.currentOffset.width + deltaX / self.currentScale
                            }

                            self.currentOffset.height = self.currentOffset.height + deltaY / self.currentScale }

                        .onEnded { value in self.previousOffset = CGSize.zero })

                    .gesture(MagnificationGesture()
                        .onChanged { value in
                            let delta = value / self.previousScale
                            self.previousScale = value
                            self.currentScale = self.currentScale * delta
                    }
                    .onEnded { value in self.previousScale = 1.0 })

            }

            VStack {

                Spacer()

                HStack {
                    Text("Menu 1").padding().cornerRadius(30).background(Color.blue).padding()
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Menu 2").padding().cornerRadius(30).background(Color.blue).padding()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

with this code I achieved:

- user can't move picture away from the screen in horizontal direction;
- user can't make picture smaller;

Comment: The `max` function to constraint the scale works fine. I think there should be a better way to do this (I mean solve the entire problem). I'll continue to investigate. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: nice clean answer but I don't understand the 150 you use in the newOffsetWidth?  I just want the edges of my image to be the limit to how far I can scroll left or right